# use python ftplib downloading but get ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, ftplib, connection-refused

I was trying use ftplib to download from a FTP server, but I get `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`
This is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import configparser
import socket

def downloadfile(downftp, remotepath,localpath):
    bufsize=1024
    fp = open(localpath,'wb')     
    downftp.set_debuglevel(2)
    downftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + remotepath, fp.write, bufsize)
    fp.close()   
    
def ftpconnect(host,username,password):
    ftp = FTP()
    ftp.connect(host=host,port=10022)
    ftp.login(username, password)
    return ftp

def uploadfile(ftp,remotepath, localpath):
    bufsize=1024
    fp=open(localpath,'rb')       
    ftp.set_debuglevel(0)
    ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + remotepath, fp, bufsize)
    fp.close()
conftp = ftpconnect('42.*.**.201','cityof********.****erver','COU***123')
downloadfile(conftp,'/world/datapacks/sys/data/pgdc/functions/food.mcfunction','food.mcfunction')
```

All error:

```
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    ftp.dir()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 575, in dir
    self.retrlines(cmd, func)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 468, in retrlines
    with self.transfercmd(cmd) as conn, \
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 399, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ftplib.py", line 361, in ntransfercmd
    source_address=self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

---

I tried  `ftp.set_pasv(True)`,it shows the same error `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

I tried `ftp.set_pasv(False)`,
and it hanging on

```
...
*cmd* 'RETR /world/datapacks/sys/data/pgdc/functions/food.mcfunction'
*put* 'RETR /world/datapacks/sys/data/pgdc/functions/food.mcfunction\r\n'
*get* '150 Opening ASCII mode data connection\n'
*resp* '150 Opening ASCII mode data connection'
```

Help please.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to successfully connect to the ftp server from command line i.e. without the python code ?  I think this should be first step to check if Connection is Refused by ftp or something wrong with python code.

```
 ftp = FTP(host=ftp_host, user=ftp_user,passwd=ftp_pass)
 ftp.login()
```

Is your upload working fine ?

Comment: I can connect the server and download a file with FileZilla

Comment: ftp.dir ftp.storlines ftp.storbinary ftp.retrlines ftp.retrbinary are all show ```ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused```.
I only can connect server with ftp.connect(),if I give connect parameter in ftp = FTP(host=ftp_host, user=ftp_user,passwd=ftp_pass) ,it will show ```ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused```,too.

Comment: Pls. run the Ftp commands in the python terminal..Also, check your firewall settings, Is port 21 open ?

Comment: my firewall is off,I tried run FTP commands in python terminal,it shows same error to me.

Comment: Now I find a way to FTP download in python without ftplib,thanks your help.